# Color overlay for PNG images

Tags: css, png, overlay

i have been 'google'ing for a few days to find out if it is possible to overlay multiple images (i.e. roof.png , walls.png) and then dynamically apply overlay colors to them (depending on the user's click on colors).

I solved the first part to colorize the roof but it gets complicated (impossible?) when I add the second layer, the walls. The 'roof.png' is 'above' the 'walls.png' and the color effect is not visible.

What I want to achieve is a coloring scheme like [here](http://dakotasteelandtrim.com/visualizer/) but not with separate images for all the colors (i.e. roof_blue.png , roof_red.png) but with css rules for the transparent roof.png.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

EDITED :

I will try to be more specific so you can concentrate on the solution (if there is one...)
Here is my HTML part :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="visualisation_area">

        </div>
        <div class="buttons_area">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
.visualisation_area {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-image:   linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5),  rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)),
                        url(../images/roof_blank.png),
                        linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5),  rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)),
                        url(../images/walls_blank.png);

    background-repeat:  no-repeat,
                        no-repeat,
                        no-repeat,
                        no-repeat;

    background-position:    right,
                            center,
                            right,
                            center;
}
```

The result can be seen [HERE](http://flexymanagement.com/buck_steel/steel_building/)
What I'm curious about is if there is a way to apply the 'blue' and 'red' gradients SEPARATELY to the roof_blank.png and walls_blank.png respectively so the colors don't mix but the roof gets blue and the walls red for example?
I have tried several combinations with divs and images but without some guidelines I'm going nowhere from this point... Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about [CCS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)?

Comment: I'd be using SVG or `canvas` frankly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [CCS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) instead of multiple files
2. You can try to create [divs with complex shapes](http://coursesweb.net/css/complex-shapes-div-css_cs)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Paulie_D I totally agree but I thought that in this particular case when OP was searching the web for a few days for a little prompt it would be enough. Also there was no code provided when I posted my answer, I always try to cover as much information in the answer as possible when it's possible. A good question is a pledge of a good answer. Last argument: These are not just links, they are titled, so if they die you'll have to spend few seconds more to google their titles. Thanks.